# using multiple image on background

Tags: css, background-image

I am getting problems on using multiple images in the background of my web pages. I used the following codes for it:

```
body{
background-image: url(images/img1.png), url(images/img2.png); }
```

The code I used gives me two images on background but I want to keep one of the image exactly on the center. How can it do so using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can do it like this

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/img1.png), url(images/img2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-position: center, top left;
}
```

Check a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/JwFTv/) here.